# XAML Namespace for Prism 6

Tags: prism, prism-6

For a couple of months I've been using Prism 6 with the following XAML namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
```

But I noticed this namespace URL (which redirects to GitHub) also exists:

```
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
```

Please confirm which namespace is the correct one to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you might know, Prism has been taken over by the [community](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/03/19/prism-grows-up.aspx) and effort has been made to bring a new release with Prism 6. The old namespace

```
xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
```

might have been in the first pre-release packages of Prism 6 that you tried. But the team decided on switching to the new namespace.

```
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
```

This is also mentioned in the [release notes for v 6.0.0](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes---6.0.0).

> - Fix XAML namespace issue (http://www.codeplex.com/prism)
> - Created new xmlns namespace http://prismlibrary.com/

So you should only be using the new namespace after upgrading to the lastest version. If you happen to see the use of an old namespace, don't hesitate to report an issue on the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1):

Go with xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/". The codeplex.com namespace is a legacy namespace which, I suppose, could go away in the future. Code comments in the source on GitHub indicate it is legacy, too.

I use the prismlibrary.com namespace in all my Prism references. Works well.